# Validates presence in Rails with Globalize not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

I'm working on a rails project with globalize, where I've a model called **Product** like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  translates :name, :description

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

The problem is that the validates is not working for the update on other locales, it's working on the first create method, but whenever I want to update the object with another locale, it doesn't check for the presence of name. Example below:

```
Product.create!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
```

Once a Product is created and has en translations, when trying to update for another locale, the validators aren't checked, example:

```
irb(main):009:0> p.update_attributes(name: "", locale: :es)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Any thoughts on how this can be acheived?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
p.update_attributes(name: "", locale: :es)
```

you are setting name attribute to ""

However, in `Product.create!` you are not passing value to 'name'
It can be used as `Product.create(name: "")!` if you want.

Comment: That's the problem, the update_attributes should fail with an empty name. The Product.create works OK, it's failing without a name

Comment: validates :name, presence: true only ensures that it is not nil. nil is different from ""

Comment: Project.create will work as it only create an instance object, but not Project.create! as validations occur when you are trying to save the object instance. ! tries to do that

Comment: you're wrong, check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. Trying to dig deeper and yes validation should have failed in your case. Would have made more sense if you were using update_attribute(name: "") instead of update_attributes(name: "", locale: :es) as the former skips validations. see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute . Will let you know id I find some answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  translates :name, :description

  validates :name, presence: true

  class Translation
    # define translation validations here
    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```